# Using WinRT library in WPF application.

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, webcam

I have followed this article here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-use-specific-winrt-api-from-desktop-apps-capturing-a-photo-using-your-webcam-into-a-wpf-app.aspx

And it all works great... but how do I get a preview in WPF?

The XAML "CaptureElement" control is not available in WPF. Is there any other way I can get a preview using the MediaCapture API?

Why would Microsoft not make this control Available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Late reply, but in case that helps folks in the future: previewing MediaCapture in WPF is difficult but possible. Here is some code sample:
https://github.com/mmaitre314/MediaCaptureWPF

Answer (score 1):

After investigating further it seems impossible to get this to work with the XAML Capture Element or any other XAML element in WPF.

I decided to port my WPF app to a Win8 application. I kept the existing back end code and referenced it using a Brokered WinRT Component. An excellent tutorial can be found here: http://devhawk.net/2014/04/25/brokered-winrt-components-step-one/ on how to create a WinRT brokered component.

Keep in mind that the app must be sideloaded and will not work for apps that you want to publish to the store.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rig up a mechanism to display the converted `BitmapImage` yourself, e.g., either in an `Image` control or as an `ImageBrush` on some surface.  To the best of my knowledge, WinRT controls cannot be hosted in WPF.

`CaptureElement` was presumably not ported to WPF because it depends on WinRT APIs, and it makes little sense to introduce a dependency into WPF for an API that is only available on Windows 8+, and which is only officially supported in Windows Store apps.

Comment: have a look at this article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj856306.aspx Some of the WinRT libraries are supported for desktop applications.