# Camera stream using MediaCapture stops working after a while?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, windows-10

I am using `Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture` to get a video stream from a Surface webcam, and display it on-screen.

```
await _mediaCap.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
    VideoDeviceId = devices?.FirstOrDefault()?.Id,
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
    PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview
});

await _mediaCap.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(
    MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, encodeProps);

_dRequest = new DisplayRequest();
_dRequest.RequestActive();
```

Periodically I grab a frame from the camera stream using:

```
using (var randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
    {
        await _mediaCap.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(properties, randomAccessStream);
    });

    await Task.Run(() => 
    { 
         randomAccessStream.Seek(0);
         using (var ioStream = randomAccessStream.AsStream())
         {
             BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
             bitmapImage.BeginInit();
             bitmapImage.StreamSource = ioStream;
             bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
             bitmapImage.EndInit();
             bitmapImage.Freeze();

             capturedImage = bitmapImage;
         }
     });
}
```

After a period of time, the stream fails with an exception:

```
"The request is invalid in the current state. Started"
```

[Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884378/why-cant-i-use-capturephototostreamasync-from-a-system-threading-timer-call-bac) to this suggest making sure that the thread that calls `CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` is the UI thread (shown above), but the issue still occurs for me. It seems to be semi-random in terms of time before occurrence, between 20 minutes to a couple hours before happening.

Note that this is a WPF app (.NET 4.6.2), [using WinRT](https://github.com/mmaitre314/MediaCaptureWPF) to utilize the `MediaCapture` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was valuable to track the number of failures in sequence, and if it reached some threshold then dispose the camera and reset controls that depended on the camera.

- Call `StopAsync()` on the `CapturePreview` object
- Call `Dispose()` on the `MediaCapture` object

I found that having my camera preview `Image` control in a view that was frequently torn down and rebuilt was much less stable than having it my "MainView" and keeping it alive constantly (if it started spamming errors like above, that same `Image` was used for reconstruction of the camera).

Other things to keep in mind:

- Mind which threads are handling various things. Naturally you'll need the UI thread for managing your `Image` control(s)
- Use of a [SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) object was quite useful in making sure that the camera was never being built, disposed, or captured from simultaneously.